# How to specify a CompilerVersion for aspnet_compiler.exe without a web.config?

Tags: asp.net, aspnet-compiler, precompile

When you precompile a directory that doesn't contain a `web.config`, the `aspnet_compiler.exe` defaults to `CompilerVersion` 2.0 and 3.5 code fails to compile. Is the following minimal `web.config` the only way to specify the `CompilerVersion`?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4"
                      type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

We integrated asp.net precompilation with our build and integration environments and don't use `web.config`s for our control library components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863%28VS.80%29.aspx) you can find its parameters. Also note that ASP.NET Compilation tool is not available with versions of ASP.NET earlier than ASP.NET version 2.0.

For .NET 2.0 these are the steps you need to do

- Start > run  and type cmd.
- set path=%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
- aspnet_compiler –v / –p c:\myproject\testsite c:\testcompile

I think that for other versions of .NET you have to cd to corresponding directory.

Also read [this](http://dotnetstep.blogspot.com/2009/06/usage-of-aspnetcompilerexe-and.html). You might find it useful.

Comment: Thanks, but I had already looked at the *available* documentation (command line options etc.) but what I am looking for is a way to do it without a web.config, hence the question.

Comment: Well, IMHO there's no other way of doing this.
Either you compile your project using commands, or use web.config.
What you can do is create pre-build action script, and compile project in different directory, then use this compiled version for further actions.